# Get items and objects bound to each list item in a Kendo ListView

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

I have a kendo listview in which each item is a combination of checkbox and some text field as shown in image below:

[image]

On clicking Save button, I need to fetch the checked elements from kendo list view. Using items() or dataItems() method, I get the list of items that represent the template but not what I actually require i.e. the items which have been checked.

How can I figure out if that particular list item is checked or not ?

Code is as follows:

```
<div id='lstItems'></div>

    var _dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    data: [{ Title: "Item 1", ID: 121 }, { Title: "Item 2" , ID: 122}, { Title: "Item 3" , ID: 123}],
                });

    $("#lstItems").kendoListView({
                    dataSource: _dataSource ,
                    template: "<div><label><input type='checkbox'/>#:Title#</label></div>"
                });
```

I have one more problem, I need to bind the entire object to a list item so that on fetching the checked items, I can get the complete object that comprises of 2 properties: Title, ID .

I am quite new to kendo.js and HTML, so not aware of much methods.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the object bound to item in Kendo ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40822732/get-the-object-bound-to-item-in-kendo-listview)

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a boolean to your ViewModel such as:

```
var _dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    data: [{ Title: "Item 1", ID: 121, checked: false }, { Title: "Item 2" , ID: 122, checked: true}, { Title: "Item 3" , ID: 123, checked: true}],
                });
```

And you can update your template such that, if there is checked to true in your dataSource and you can set your checkbox to checked state and Non checked state when checked is set to false.

When you can click on save do a .filter() on your dataSource to get the items that have been checked.

```
dataSource.filter( { field: "checked",  value: "true" });
var view = dataSource.view();
console.log(view);
```